# Can't retrieve XMPP JID from NSMutableDictionary iOS app.

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsmutabledictionary, xmppframework

When I receive XMPP Presence in the app ,  I am adding its contents to a `NSMutableDictionary` to send it across another `ViewController`.If I use `NSLog` to see the contents of this dictionary , I can see everything fine.But when I access this `NSMutableDictionary` from another `ViewController` I can't find the JID.Rest of the things are stored fine.

This is what I am doing while storing the  XMPP Presence contents i e JID and Name.

```
 - (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceivePresence:(XMPPPresence *)presence
 {
     NSString *fromUser = [[presence from]user];      //name of user
     NSString *fromUserJID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[presence from]] ;
     NSLog(@"presence from user JID :- %@", fromUserJID);   // This shows the JID.

      [_locationDictionary setObject:fromUser forKey:@"fromUser"];
      [_locationDictionary setObject:fromUserJID forKey:@"fromJID"];
      NSLog(@"locationary dictionary :- %@",_locationDictionary );  // This shows name as well as JID.

       // add to array
    [_presenceArray addObject:_locationDictionary];
```

Now when I am trying to access this in another ViewController I do this:-

```
    NSString *str=view.annotation.title;        //This has the name of the user.
    NSLog(@"annotation title :- %@", str);      
   for (NSDictionary *obj in appDelegate.presenceArray)
   {
       NSString *titleString = [obj objectForKey:@"fromUser"];

       if ([str isEqualToString:titleString])                 //for the same username I need the JID
       {
           NSString *jidString = [obj objectForKey:@"fromJID"];
           [ dict setObject:jidString forKey:@"jid"];      //dict is NSMutableDictionary

           NSLog(@"retrieved jid is :- %@", dict); // THIS IS NULL
```

Comment: jidString have some value or it nil? And did you initialise your dict?

Comment: where did you initalise your "dict"?

Comment: dict is initialised, in ViewDidLoad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [presence from]  will give XMPPJid which is NSObject type.

```
XMPPJID *jid = [presence from];
```

Try to get Jid string this way

```
NSString *fromUserJID = [[presence from] full];//Will give Jid have user, resource, domain

//OR

NSString *fromUserJID = [presence fromStr]; //Only give Jid of user.
```